# Gulp сборка в разные styl файлы

Tags: css, gulp, сборка

Сейчас есть конфигурация Gulp, в которой все скрипты пишутся в один .css файл. Но нужно отделить файлы с суффиксом -ie (fname-ie.styl) и собирать их отдельно, рядом с (общим) .min.css файлом.

```
gulp.task('styles', () => (
    gulp.src('app/styles/*.styl')
        .pipe(stylus({
            use: [
                importIfExist(),
                rupture()
            ],
            'include css': true
        }))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/styles'))
));
```

Comment: Вероятно можно разделить стримы и обработать их разными путями. Но, думаю, нужно очень мощное колдунство. Гораздо большее, чем потери от запуска другого таска.

Answer (score 6):

Я использую такой вариант сборки:

```
gulp.task('styles', () => (
    gulp.src(['app/styles/*.styl', '!app/styles/*-ie.styl'])
        .pipe(stylus({
            use: [
                importIfExist(),
                rupture()
            ],
            'include css': true
        }))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/styles'))
));
gulp.task('styles-ie', () => (
    gulp.src('app/styles/*-ie.styl')
        .pipe(stylus({
            use: [
                importIfExist(),
                rupture()
            ],
            'include css': true
        }))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/styles'))
));
```

Comment: нет, так оно все в один файл ложит... здесь нужно правило, что бы с -ie не ложило и второе правило, что бы с -ie в css отдельно собирало...

Comment: для этого используйте отдельный таск.

Answer (score 2):

Для таких ситуаций стоит сделать отдельный таск.